# Async where clause

Tags: sql, node.js, async-await, knex.js

I'm using knex 0.14.2 with Node 8 and I'm playing with async/await statement. But I just find a case where I need to build a `where` clause depending on a request: I build my main query, do a `select` and add a `where` to the main one, depending on the result. So I tried

```
mainQuery.where(async function() {
  const res = await knex('table').select();
  if(res.x) this.where('y', 'x');
})
```

but when tracing the queries, I saw the main one didn't have the where clause and the select was executed after it.

I suppose the `await` is not very well supported but is there a proper way to do such thing?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
const res = await knex('table').select();
await mainQuery.where(function() {
  if(res.x) this.where('y', 'x');
})
```

Knex will never support resolving internally builder method callbacks asychronously (in other words it will not support callback functions which would return promises).

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that, but since there is no other way around I'll do that. Thank you